# Classic ASP Error 80004005 when trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to connect a classic ASP webpage to SQL Server 2008, and whatever I do I keep getting this...

```
error '80004005'
```

It then proceeds to tell me the line where the error is, and that is all.

My connection code is as follows

```vb
<%
Dim Stock
Dim Stock_cmd
Dim Stock_numRows

Set Stock_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Stock_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_DVerto_STRING
Stock_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Part_Number FROM dbo.Stock_Header WHERE Part_Number = ?" 
Stock_cmd.Prepared = true
Stock_cmd.Parameters.Append Stock_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 15, Stock__MMColParam2) ' adVarChar

Set Stock = Stock_cmd.Execute
Stock_numRows = 0
%>
```

Connection File

```vb
<%
' FileName="Connection_odbc_conn_dsn.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="false"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
Dim MM_DVerto_STRING
MM_DVerto_STRING = "dsn=CMD SQL;uid=web;"
%>
```

Any help would be greatly accepted!

Comment: I can only assume that you are connection to Access. Have you tried searching for this error? It seems there are thousands and thousands of examples of this and how to fix it. https://www.google.com/search?q=classic+asp+error+%2780004005%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: My old school ASP is a bit rusty. But, don't you need to create a connection object and attach that to the command object? Your code is setting the connection to a string value.

Comment: My connection is to a SQL Server, and I have googled it, but none of the results have fixed the issue yet

Comment: The connection is being handled by Dreamweaver, and it works fine on a non SQLServer db.

Comment: Try changing the value of `MM_DVerto_STRING` to a SQL Server OLEDB connection string - examples here. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I will note that Dreamweaver can see the tables. When I open the webpage in a browser I get this error.

Comment: @MartinSoles Yes just a  bit rusty the `.ActiveConnection` property can accept either a `ADODB.Connection` object or a connection string and the `ADODB.Connection` is created based off it *(my preferred way to add connection to the Command object)*.

Comment: What is your environment? Are you running x86 or x64? If you are running 64 bit you could be having issues with the DSN being registered in the wrong ODBC Data Sources panel. If the website is running the 32 bit mode it will look in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC` for the data source if not it will look in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC` for it. At the moment it's looking in the wrong location most likely.

Comment: You can check this by running the correct version of `odbcad32.exe` *(Data Source Administrator)* to see if the DSN is listed. 32 Bit *(on a 64 Bit System)* - `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` 64 Bit - `%SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe` *(This is also the default location on 32 Bit systems)*.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for the help, I think (not 100% sure as we did a lot of tinkering with permissions) might have solved the issue.

Comment: Permissions 9 out of 10 times is a red herring, I've come across this issue in enough environments over the years to know.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 80004005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306345) is:

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Most likely your web server is missing an ODBC connection named `CMD SQL`.

If not, here is the full list of possible causes from that MSDN link:

> - The Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 or Windows 2000 user account that is used to process the request for the ASP page does not have sufficient
>     permissions to read the registry key that stores the specified DSN's
>     configuration information.
> - The System ODBC DSN that is specified in the ADO connection string does not exist on the IIS server.
> - The ASP Application or Session variable that is initialized in the ASP application's Global.asa file (or in an ASP page that is accessed
>     before the page that contains the database connection code) is used to
>     specify the ADO connection string. This connection string variable is
>     not initialized when the code to open the database connection is run.
>     To confirm this, add a Response.Write statement before the line of
>     code that opens the database connection to display the connection
>     string that is stored in the variable.

Comment: Just think OP you could have *Googled* the error code yourself, instead of someone regurgitating the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Tried most of the above and nothing changes.

Comment: The issue is more likely the OPs architecture *(x86 or x64)* and having the DSN registered in the wrong place.